# Hackerrank | Maximize it

Tags: python, python-2.7

You are given a function f(X)=X^2.

You are also given K lists. The  list consists of Ni elements.

You have to pick exactly one element from each list so that the equation below is maximized:

S=(f(X1)+f(X2)+...+f(Xk))%M

Xi denotes the element picked from the ith list . Find the maximized value Smax obtained.

% denotes the modulo operator.

This is the code that I have written.

```
n=list(map(int,raw_input().split()))
l=n[0]
div=n[1]
b=list()
for i in range(0,l):
    a=list()
    a.extend(map(int,raw_input().split()))
    b.append(max(a))
    su=0
for j in b:
    su+=j*j

print su%div
```

I am not sure why the code is failing for some test cases.I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I saw some answer in which they were using Cartesian product.

```
import itertools

k, m = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
a = []
for i in range(k):
    a.append(raw_input().split(' ')[1:])

mx = 0
for tp in itertools.product(*a):
    res = sum([int(x)**2 for x in tp]) % m
    if res > mx:
        mx = res

print mx
```

Comment: If your lists are `[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]` and your modulus is 6, you’re not going to want to pick the maximum value from *all* the lists.

Comment: Are you given *M*?

Comment: Offtopic: is it possible to not bruteforce it?

Comment: @DJV I think that this is a variation of the knapsack problem. However, by using the mathematical properties of the modulus you should be able to greatly reduce the amount of work: for each item in the list you can apply the function in advance and apply the modulus, which may allow you to find a maximum (e.g. the modulus minus one) more easily.

Comment: @DJV if there is an optimal solution you can: -- split the given lists in two roughly equal groups. -- compute all possible sums mod M for both groups -- replace the second group with M - 1 - itself  -- combine the groups of sums and sort them keeping track of group membership. -- If and only if there is an optimal solution you'll find two equal items next to each other one from the first group one from the second.

Answer (score 2):

Following code in Python3.

```
import itertools

(K, N) = map(int, input().strip().split(' '))

# reading the K lines and appending lists to 'L'
L = list()
for i in range(K):
    l = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
    n = l[0]
    L.append(l[1:])
    assert len(L[i]) == n

S_max = 0
L_max = None

# Looping through Cartesian product of list and getting max sum.
for l in itertools.product(*L):
    s = sum([x**2 for x in l]) % N

    if s > S_max:
        S_max = s
        L_max = l

print(S_max)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product
K,M = map(int,input().split())
N = (list(map(int,input().split()))[1:] for _ in range(K))
results = map(lambda x: sum(i**2 for i in x)%M,product(*N))
print(max(results))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
from itertools import product
K,M = map(int,input().split())
nums = []
for _ in range(K):
    row = map(int,input().split()[1:])
    nums.append(map(lambda x:x**2%M, row))
print(max(map(lambda x: sum(x)%M, product(*nums))))
```